# Russian anthem, Lord Save the People

Tags: identify-this-song

I have heard that there was a popular anthem in Russia from before the revolution called "Lord Save the People", but I have not been able to find much out about it. Does anyone know if there are modern recordings or extant sheet music?

Answer (score 2):

It may be [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbeXrs1gCHE). Although it doesn't seem to be a anthem, but rather a chant of sorts. The official anthem of pre-revolution Russia (Russian Empire) was ["Lord save the Tzar"](https://youtu.be/3qUFErfzIMc) (Боже, Царя храни!). I'm not sure if there was something before that.

[Here is](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) the list of all know Russian anthems, including the early unofficial one and the short living ones between the empire and the USSR.